# Text Field within UIScrollView not showing cursor ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios7

I'm using text field within a UIScrollView of Class 'KeyBoardAvoidingsScrollView'. But when i try to tap on text field it is not showing cursor.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this `KeyBoardAvoidingsScrollView`? what will it do? did u download this class file from github or this is your own class?

Comment: check whether the scroll view user interaction is not disabled

Comment: I have downloaded KeyBoardAvoidingsScrollView class from github.

Comment: Nassif scrool view user interaction is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

[text_field setEditable:NO];